# How to create xml sitemap of all the Django project detail page urls

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to get all the urls for specific Django project detail pages for instance:

```
path('/mysite/speical/<pk>',views.DetalView.as_view(),name='detail')

/mysite/special/1390u20
/mysite/special/930nfdn
/mysite/special/29093nn
```

How do I print all these urls into an xml file in the shell? I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemap import SpeicalSitemap

sitemaps = {
    yoursitemap: YourSitemap
}

path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemap'),
```

Create a file named sitemap.py inside your app:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from yourapp.models import Yourmodel


class YourSiteMap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'monthly'
    priority = 0.9

    def items(self):
        return yourmodel.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.last_mod_date "Here your put a last mod date defined in your model if you have it."
```

To create the right route to your objects, you need to put a method in your model called "get_absolute_url", let's create:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class YourModel(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('name_of_your_route', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```